# How do I programmatically create a new content type?

Tags: nodes

I'm building a module (my_module) in Drupal 7. It has some functionality and also
will create a new content type. In my_module.install, I implemented `hook_install()` (`my_module_install()`).

Can I use more `hook_install()` to create a new content type (`my_module_install()`) in this module?
If the answer is *yes*, how should I do this? Otherwise, should I do this in another module?

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I would consider using the [Features](http://drupal.org/project/features) module. The module enables exporting a subset of websites structure into a single feature to facilitate re-using this feature elsewhere.

Also, Features module enabled exporting content types/fields easily, you would just tick a certain content type and Voila! The Features module will generate Drupal hooks for you, and also export the code into a module.

Comment: Thank You! I'm not sure I'll use Features module now, but it helped me understand how to create my content type.